Degradation via electrolysis and electrode surface area
What is the relationship between electrode surface area and processes such as electrolysis/electrode polarization?
Let's say for example I want a fixed electric field between two electrodes in a solution, but I want to avoid degradation of those electrodes over time.
Am I better off choosing a large or small surface area for a given voltage/electrode spacing?
I am a novice in these processes so if anyone can recommend some basic tutorial on this process please go ahead.

If you change the surface area of the electrode, it will not change degradation of the electrode. Degradation does not depend on the surface of the electrode.

Also, in first approximation, the distance between the electrode has no effect. This is not like a capacitor between the two electrodes. You could start with a basic introductory book on electrochemistry. The Bard and Faulkner (Electrochemical Methods: Fundamentals and Applications) is often used. Here is a good website if you want to understand the practical aspect of running a simple electrochemistry experiment: https://sop4cv.com/index.html

Certainly, the larger the electrodes, the less degradation per unit area. Simply, with larger electrodes, damage is spread out over the surface. That doesn't decrease degradation, just diffuses it. If the same mass of electrode is used, it would last the same.
